# CloudConvert API v2 The tasks field is required

Tags: php

Я пытаюсь настроить API, но при попытке отправить запрос выдает ошибку

```
Uncaught CloudConvert\Exceptions\HttpClientException: tasks: The tasks field is required.
```

Мне нужно отправить файл для конвертации со своего компьютера и получить в ответ html. Где моя ошибка? Заранее спасибо!

```
use \CloudConvert\CloudConvert;
use \CloudConvert\Models\Job;
use \CloudConvert\Models\Task;

$cloudconvert = new CloudConvert([
    'api_key' => 'мой ключ',
    'sandbox' => false
]);


$job = (new Job())
   ->addTask(
       (new Task('import/upload', 'import-my-file'))
       ->set('file', fopen($DocumentPath, 'r'))
     )
   ->addTask(
       (new Task('convert', 'convert-doc-to-html'))
         ->set('input_format', 'doc')
         ->set('output_format', 'html')
         ->set('engine', 'office')
         ->set('input', ["import-my-file"])
     )
   ->addTask(
       (new Task('export/url', 'export-my-file'))
         ->set('input', ["convert-doc-to-html"])
         ->set('inline', false)
         ->set('archive_multiple_files', false)
     ); 
     
$cloudconvert->jobs()->create($job);
$uploadTask = $job->getTasks()->whereName('import-my-file')[0];

$cloudconvert->tasks()->upload($uploadTask, fopen($DocumentPath, 'r'), 'myfile.doc');
```

Comment: Видимо у вас нет файла или он не доступен на чтение по пути $DocumentPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл был открыт. Вот решение

```
/* решение */
    $file = rtrim(file_get_contents($file, FILE_TEXT)); 
    
            $file = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($file, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
   /* решение */
            $job = (new Job())
            ->addTask(
                (new Task('import/upload', 'import-my-file'))
                ->set('file', $file)
                )
            ->addTask(
                (new Task('convert', 'convert-'.$file_format.'-to-html'))
                    ->set('input_format', $file_format)
                    ->set('output_format', 'html')
                    ->set('engine', 'office')
                    ->set('input', ["import-my-file"])
                )
            ->addTask(
                (new Task('export/url', 'export-my-file'))
                    ->set('input', ['convert-'.$file_format.'-to-html'])
                    ->set('inline', false)
                    ->set('archive_multiple_files', false)
                ); 
                
            $cloudconvert->jobs()->create($job);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]